# Building libgdx project using VSTS

Tags: android, libgdx, azure-devops

I am trying to setup a VSTS build for my LibGdx project. In my VSTS build definition I am using the standard Gradle build step, in which the build fails.

My stack trace from VSTS looks like this:

```
07:50:40.981 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Starting Build
07:50:40.983 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Gradle user home: C:\java\gradle\user
07:50:40.984 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Current dir: D:\a\1\s
07:50:40.987 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings file: null
07:50:40.988 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Build file: null
07:50:41.019 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Starting to build the build sources.
07:50:41.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Gradle source dir does not exist. We leave.
07:50:41.024 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found env project properties: []
07:50:41.026 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found system project properties: []
07:50:41.725 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.mvnsettings.DefaultLocalMavenRepositoryLocator] No local repository in Settings file defined. Using default path: C:\Users\buildguest\.m2\repository
07:50:42.170 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor] Timing: Processing settings took: 1.144 secs
07:50:42.174 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
07:50:42.368 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: D:\a\1\s\gradle.properties
07:50:42.369 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] project property file does not exists. We continue!
07:50:42.371 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Projects loaded. Root project using empty build file.
07:50:42.373 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Included projects: [root project 's']
07:50:42.733 [INFO] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Evaluating root project 's' using empty build file.
07:50:42.747 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 0.013 secs
07:50:42.751 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] All projects evaluated.
07:50:42.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
07:50:42.783 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
07:50:42.784 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
07:50:42.785 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
07:50:42.786 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Task 'build' not found in root project 's'.
07:50:42.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
07:50:42.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
07:50:42.788 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
07:50:42.790 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
07:50:42.791 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
07:50:42.792 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
07:50:42.793 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 10.167 secs
07:50:42.801 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache artifact cache (C:\java\gradle\user\caches\modules-2) was closed 0 times.
07:50:42.803 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 0 resolution results binary files in 0.0 secs
07:50:42.805 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory] In-memory dependency metadata cache closed. Repos cached: 0, cache instances: 0, modules served from cache: 0, artifacts: 0
Error: d:\a\1\s\7Seas\core\gradlew.bat failed with return code: 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (d:\a\_tasks\Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4\1.122.0\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\toolrunner.js:569:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
##[error]Error: d:\a\1\s\7Seas\core\gradlew.bat failed with return code: 1
##[section]Finishing: gradlew build
```

I am suspecting that the build is trying to execute the 'build' command in the wrong directory. Shouldn't the Current dir be: D:\a\1\s\ProjName ?

My gradle wrapper file is here:

```
@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
@rem ##########################################################################
@rem
@rem  Gradle startup script for Windows
@rem
@rem ##########################################################################

@rem Set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal

set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%

@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=

@rem Find java.exe
if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome

set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:init
@rem Get command-line arguments, handling Windows variants

if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args

:win9xME_args
@rem Slurp the command line arguments.
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
set _SKIP=2

:win9xME_args_slurp
if "x%~1" == "x" goto execute

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*

:execute
@rem Setup the command line

set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar

@rem Execute Gradle
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end
@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd

:fail
rem Set variable GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
if  not "" == "%GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
exit /b 1

:mainEnd
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal

:omega
```

and my gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
#Thu Oct 12 08:51:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip
```

Comment: How do you create this project? What's the result if you build it through gradlew directory on your local machine? Could you share the simple sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: It is a project I have worked on over several months now, and have now decided to use VSTS as a build server. The project was created using the LibGdx project generator. The project builds perfectly on my local machine. I have since I asked started over with a new project, made sure that could build in VSTS and then moved code, tests and assets stepwise, making sure it could continue to build. It is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is that you can create a new project and make sure it could build in VSTS, then move the code to the new project.